# Why does Visual Studio 2019 show errors for valid azure-pipelines.yml files?

Tags: visual-studio, azure-devops

The azure-pipelines.yml files in my solutions are working. In Visual Studio Code I use the Azure Pipelines extension and it shows no errors in the YAML syntax, but Visual Studio reports many errors for the same valid YAML files.

So far, the errors seem be only on the the NuGetCommand@2 task type and its parameters.

Why does Visual Studio report these errors? Is there option to make Visual Studio recognize the syntax?

I am using Visual Studio version 16.8.3.

[image]

Comment: If you're not using custom schema, then please refer this answer..
https://stackoverflow.com/a/77134947/672891

Comment: @RikinPatel That answer seems to apply to VS Code but the problem I was asking about here is for Visual Studio. I never had any issue with the syntax highlighter in VS Code.

Comment: Oh, yes sorry its my bad...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like this is a known issue, "fixed" by disabling validation, that may not yet have made it into release:

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1276696/validation-errors-when-opening-azure-pipelinesyml.html

Comment: Also, as much as I love Visual Studio, having to wait on Microsoft to triage, fix, and release something like this just makes VS Code more attractive - there's already an extension out there for this purpose: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TomAustin.azure-devops-yaml-pipeline-validator

Comment: I have enjoyed using the VS Code extension for Azure Pipelines. VS Code and Visual Studio are each good at various tasks. I tend to keep them both open and use whichever is better for what I'm working on. I tried updating Visual Studio to the very latest version 16.8.5 but the Azure Pipeline syntax issue is still present.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure the Azure Pipelines extension in VS Code to use the yamlschema from your Azure DevOps Organization, this prevents false Problems. See [README](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-vscode#readme) of Azure Pipelines for VS Code, heading [Specific schema](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-vscode#specific-schema).

So something like this:

1. Visit https://dev.azure.com/YOUR-ORG/_apis/distributedtask/yamlschema and save the output as YOUR-ORG-schema.json.
2. Edit your VS Code Settings (UI) and place the full path to YOUR-ORG-schema.json in the input field "Azure-pipelines: Custom Schema File".

Comment: I was going to try this but I just realized that the problem has been fixed in Visual Studio now. I upgraded to version 16.10 yesterday an that seems to have fixed it. It might have been fixed 1 or more versions before that but I was not looking lately.