# Visual Studio Code showing error: Property Stages is not allowed, Property parameters is not allowed

Tags: visual-studio-code, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I created reusable templates from Azure DevOps yaml pipeline. The build.yaml you see below is one such template.

When I push code, the pipeline successfully runs on Azure DevOps without complaining. However Visual Studio Code complains as I hover on parameters or stages.

```
Property Stages is not allowed 
Property parameters is not allowed
```

Am I missing any settings here? Why VS Code shows errors while azure devops runs the same successfully?

[image: Property parameters is not allowed error shown by VS Code]

[image: Property stages is not allowed error shown by VS Code]

And interestingly, I have another template in the same directory, which does not show any such error messages. What am I missing? I restarted vs code, still same.

[image: VS Code showing no error with another yaml azure devops template]

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I observed this problem with both Visual Studio Code as well as Visual Studio 2022 Preview.

This lead me to think, I renamed the file build.yaml to **build-stage.yaml**. This fixed  the issue finally. May be build is some keyword kind of thing internally.

Comment: I had similar errors in VS2022 with a file called "azure-pipelines-deploy.yml". Renaming it to "azure-pipelines-deployment.yml" solved the problem.

Comment: Seems as if it must be a 3 part file name (aaa-bbb-ccc.yml)

Comment: I'm still encountering this in VS2022 with a 3-part file name (aaa-bbb-ccc.yml)

Comment: renaming to **build-stage.yaml** worked for me.

Comment: I still got this error with VSC version 1.77.0 in 2023

Comment: Sure and cute, but... **why** is it so? I will get into the source eventually to figure out this over-confusing nuance... I see this, and its schema is different, so is it related?: https://deployer.org/schema.json

Answer (score 5):

If the file name is `deploy.yml` you can rename it to `deploy-stage.yml`

Answer (score 4):

It is a schema issue.

[image: File Schema]

**Solution:**

1. Install the [Azure Pipelines](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-azure-devops.azure-pipelines) extension if not already installed.
2. Create `.vscode` >> `settings.json` root of your project folder.
3. Add following content in `settings.json` file.

```
{
    "files.associations": {
        "**/*.yml": "azure-pipelines"
    }
}
```

4. Enjoy...

[image]

Comment: I had the same issue, and your image led me to the answer. I simply needed to click that "Deployer Recipe" at the bottom-right screen, and when the dropdown appears - just choose the relevant schema. In my case it was "GitHub Workflow".
Effectively, it sort of did the same. In my settings.json it added the following:  
```
"yaml.schemas": {
    "https://json.schemastore.org/github-workflow.json": "**/.github/*.yml"
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

I made a similar error go away by posting a comment to the top of the .yml file:

`# yaml-language-server: $schema='none'`

The link to the page that I found the hint: https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2020/11/25/how-to-configure-yaml-schema-to-make-editing-files-easier#schema_association_without_a_file_name_pattern

*Edit: don't have enough reputation to comment on the prior questions asking for a link to this. Also unsure if it is the correct link.*

Answer (score -1):

I found this helpful [Visual Studio Code showing error: Property Stages is not allowed, Property parameters is not allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69493762/visual-studio-code-showing-error-property-stages-is-not-allowed-property-param). Basically VSCode is trying to detect the yml schema, and in my case, it's using something from delivery.org. So adding this config comment to the top of the file was enough to redirect the schema server property and clear the errors.

Comment: The link goes back to this page?

Comment: Can someone please correct the link here?